# Easier way to get a field's value when given a node object from node_load

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to get a CCK text field's value using node_load() - the code goes like `$nodeObject->field_name['und']['0']['value'];`

Is there a simpler built-in function like get_cck_field_value(node $nodeObject) that I can use, or do I write it myself?

Comment: I think there is nothing so. Please share if you make one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) like this:

```
field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
```

Also see [What's best practice when working with the `language['und']`?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24699/whats-best-practice-when-working-with-the-languageund).

Comment: Thank you for the link you provided `field_get_items()` is great, and so is `entity_metadata_wrapper()`... does any of them include an additional call to the DB? I shouldn't think so, but still...

Comment: @harijari Nice finding

Answer (score 1):

You can also use methods provided by Entity API module:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$field_value = $wrapper->field_name->value();
```